# Android iBeacon getting DataProviderException

Tags: ibeacon-android

Although i am using the lib from this link,

[Proximity Kit download Page](http://www.proximitykit.com/kits/1284/download/android)

which i believe it is the latest version, i am getting a `DataProviderException` that tells me to upgrade to the pro version.

I get this exception using the `IBeaconDataNotifier` interface when trying to get information on beacon data update.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

Make sure you are using `com.radiusnetworks.proximity.ibeacon.IBeaconManager` instead of `com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconManager`.  You need to be using the class in the `com.radiusnetworks.proximity.ibeacon` package to access Pro features.

Comment: I Forgot to tell that i was already using that class as the example code says. :)

Comment: For some reason , it throws the exception when app is running in foreground, but when running in background the exception is not thrown

Comment: I would have to see your code to troubleshoot further.  Can send a zipfile containing your code (or a link to a Github repo) to support@radiusnetworks.com?  Alternately, you can put some excerpts in your question above.